# Which versions of DataStax Enterprise have the fix for CVE-2020-13946?

Tags: cassandra

Early versions of Apache Cassandra had a vulnerability that could potentially allow a local attacker to manipulate the RMI registry to capture credentials and gain access to the JMX interface ([CVE-2020-13946](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-13946)).

Which versions of DataStax Enterprise have the fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CVE-2020-13946 has been patched in [DataStax Enterprise (DSE)](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) versions 5.1.19, 6.0.13, 6.7.10 and 6.8.3 (internal reference DSP-21264).

Upgrade to the corresponding latest DSE minor versions to mitigate the risk to your cluster. Cheers!